# How to use custom view with in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I want to add a custom view in TableViewHeader. But when I run the following code it creates a Cycle and app stuck for any user interaction.

```
import UIKit
class ExpandableView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNamelbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightArrowImgView: UIImageView!
    var isExpanded = false
    var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkMarkView: UIImageView!

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpView()
    }

    private func setUpView() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ExpandableView", bundle: bundle)
        self.contentView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.center = self.center
        contentView.autoresizingMask = []
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }
}
```

I am using it as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 60)
    let expandabelView = ExpandableView(frame: frame)
    return expandabelView
}
```

And it shows following error on run.

[image: See Errors]

Comment: Still not working same issue again

Comment: `init(coder:)` will call `setupView()` that calls `UINib(nibName:bundle:)` so it will call again `init(coder:)`. So why do you call ``UINib(nibName:bundle:)`` in `initWithCoder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many other ways, but I recommend you to make your `ExpandableView` reusable to improve performance.

---

**First of all**, simplify your `ExpandableView` class:

```
import UIKit

class ExpandableView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var userImgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNamelbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightArrowImgView: UIImageView!
    var isExpanded = false

    @IBOutlet weak var checkMarkView: UIImageView!
}
```

Please do not miss that the superclass is `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, not `UIView`.

**Second**, check the settings of your `ExpandableView.xib`:

The **Custom View** setting of the defined view needs to be `ExpandableView`.

[image: Custom View of the view]

When you cannot choose `ExpandableView` from the pull down list, you may need to input manually. Do not forget to check **Inherit Module From Target**.

The Custom View setting of the **File's Owner** needs to be empty.

[image: File's Owner]

If there's some class already set, remove it manually.

Confirm all **Outlets** are connected properly to your `ExpandableView`.

[image: Outlets]

(You should better reconnect them all, after you modified your xib.)

You may need to re-structure your view hierarchy and/or **constraints**.

**Third**, modify your view controller holding the table view.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        //...
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ExpandableView", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "ExpandableView")
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 60
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let expandabelView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ExpandableView")
        // Frame size should be represented with constraints.
        return expandabelView
    }
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you create custom `UIView`, it should follow this if you want to use it init with frame.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    //This should be contentview of your xib
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    let nibName = "CustomView"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    private func xibSetup()
    {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)
        self.view.autoresizesSubviews = true
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(self.view)
        self.view.frame = self.frame


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to **load** view from **nib**, just load it and then add subview to your view. Then set content view's `frame` and set autoresizing mask of content view correctly

```
private func setUpView() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ExpandableView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
}
```